# Cannot create a new React application with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I encountered this problem when creating a new React application (after executing the `npx create-react-app my-app` command):

```
    ➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

_r [RequestError]: read ECONNRESET
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/aldaspan/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs:154:14361)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at ClientRequest.o.emit (/home/aldaspan/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs:149:59453)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:211:20) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  timings: {
    start: 1639471914529,
    socket: 1639471914529,
    lookup: 1639471914530,
    connect: 1639471922067,
    secureConnect: undefined,
    upload: undefined,
    response: undefined,
    end: undefined,
    error: 1639471922468,
    abort: undefined,
    phases: {
      wait: 0,
      dns: 1,
      tcp: 7537,
      tls: undefined,
      request: undefined,
      firstByte: undefined,
      download: undefined,
      total: 7939
    }
  }
}

Node.js v17.2.0

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /home/aldaspan/galog/react-shop has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

> Operating system: Ubuntu 21.10,
> Node -v: v17.2.0,
> nodejs --version: v12.22.5,
> npm -v: 8.1.4

I am new to React, and I have been looking for this problem for several days, but I haven't found a real solution yet.

**After lowering the Node (`sudo n 16.13.1`) version, it prompts other errors:**

```
YN0000: Done with warnings in 5m 4s
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/scripts/init.js'
Require stack:
- /home/aldaspan/react-shop/[eval]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at [eval]:2:20
    at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:129:12)
    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:305:38)
    at node:internal/process/execution:75:19
    at [eval]-wrapper:6:22
    at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:74:60) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/aldaspan/react-shop/[eval]' ]
}

Aborting installation.
  node  has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you are using the recommended version of [`nodejs`](https://nodejs.org/en/). And for that you could use the [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from npm:

```js
npm install n -g 
n stable
// if one of the above commands does not pass, you could make use of sudo
sudo npm install n -g 
sudo n stable
```

If you have installed globally `create-react-app`, which you shouldn't since we now use `npx`,
go ahead and remove it:

```js
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
// if it does not pass, you could make use of sudo
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

After fallowing the above steps, delete the project you attempted to create and start over with:

```js
npx create-react-app my-app
```